# One year stay in Iraq—requirements

Tags: visa, taxes, iraq, income-requirements

Iraq offers to US citizens a [multi-entry one-year *tourist* visa](https://www.iraqiembassy.us/page/visas-to-iraq) for a fee of US$150.

This is not a residence question, but since it concerns a long stay, it probably would be flagged off-topic in Travel.SE

**Does it require proof of income (cited page doesn't mention any)?  Does staying that long (as a *tourist*) require paying taxes (other than VAT) to Iraq?**